# Problema de conflito na comunicação do Arduino RFID + Rede Nanoshield Ethernet

Tags: arduino

Boa tarde, estou com uma dificuldade na criação de um programa arduino que faça a leitura de uma TAG RFID e o mesmo faça a validação da TAG em um banco de dados mysql. Já tentei diversas formas, mas sem sucesso. Testei primeiramente um exemplo RFID que funcionou perfeitamente. Depois testei um código somente de rede e também funcionou perfeitamente, mas quando tento integrar os 2 códigos para funcionarem em conjunto o mesmo para de funcionar. Acredito que seja algum tipo conflito de comunicação pois tanto o RFID como a Rede utilizam o SPI do arduino.

Abaixo segue exemplo do Código Fonte Arduino.

```html
/*
-------- CONTROLE DE ACESSO RFID + BANCO DE DADOS------------------
===================================================================
Objetivo do programa é através de tags de RFID cadastradas em 
um banco de dados mysql, permitir a entrada de funcionários em
determinado local caso o mesmo tenha permissão cadastrada.
=============================================================
By George in 14/12/2017
*/
 
//Bibliotecas
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Nanoshield_Ethernet.h>
#include <Nanoshield_EEPROM.h>
#include <SD.h>
 
//Pinos
#define LED_VERDE 6
#define LED_VERMELHO 7
#define BUZZER 5
#define SS_PIN 2
#define RST_PIN 9

//#define RELE 5
#define BOTAO A0
#define SENSOR A2
#define REDE 10

char inString[32]; // string for incoming serial data
int stringPos = 0; // string index counter
boolean startRead = false; // is reading?
String uidTag = "";
String enderecoMac = "5410EC678A54"; // Mac da Placa de Rede Nanoshield w5500
String readString;
int portaLiberada = 0;
int contadorAtualizacao = 0;
char st[20];
 
String IDtag = ""; //Variável que armazenará o ID da Tag
bool Permitido = false; //Variável que verifica a permissão 
 
//Vetor responsável por armazenar os ID's das Tag's cadastradas
//Utilizar esse vetor somente para realização de testes sem a conexão com banco de dados.
String TagsCadastradas[] = {"781417246", 
                            "ID_2",
                            "ID_3"};
 
MFRC522 LeitorRFID(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);    // Cria uma nova instância para o leitor e passa os pinos como parâmetro
byte mac[6];
Nanoshield_EEPROM eeprom(1, 1, 0, true);
IPAddress server(147,1,0,84);  // numeric IP for Google (no DNS)
EthernetClient client; 
 
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);             // Inicializa a comunicação Serial
  SPI.begin();                    // Inicializa comunicacao SPI 
  LeitorRFID.PCD_Init();          // Inicializa o leitor RFID          mfrc522
  pinMode(LED_VERDE, OUTPUT);     // Declara o pino do led verde como saída
  pinMode(LED_VERMELHO, OUTPUT);  // Declara o pino do led vermelho como saída
  pinMode(BUZZER, OUTPUT);        // Declara o pino do buzzer como saída
  pinMode(SS_PIN, OUTPUT);        // Declara o pino do SS_PIN do RFID como saída
  pinMode(REDE, OUTPUT);          // Declara o pino do REDE como saída
  //pinMode(RELE, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_VERDE, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(LED_VERMELHO, LOW);

  //Abertura da comunicação de REDE
  eeprom.begin();
  eeprom.startReading(0x00FA);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("MAC address: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    mac[i] = eeprom.read();
    Serial.print(mac[i], HEX);
    Serial.print(":");
  }
  mac[5] = eeprom.read();
  Serial.println(mac[5], HEX);

  Ethernet.begin(mac);            //Inicializando dispositivo de rede
  Serial.print("My IP address: ");
  for (byte thisByte = 0; thisByte < 4; thisByte++) {
    Serial.print(Ethernet.localIP()[thisByte], DEC);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  
  //Verifica a conexão do arduino com o servidor 84
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("Servidor Conectado");
    //client.println();
  }
  else{
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
  
}
 
void loop() {  
  Leitura();  //Chama a função responsável por fazer a leitura das Tag's
  VerificaBotao(); //Verifica se o botão foi pressionado e libera a porta 
}

void VerificaBotao(){
  if (analogRead(BOTAO) > 900) {
    while (analogRead(BOTAO) > 900) {
      ;
    }
    acessoLiberado();
  }  
} 
void Leitura(){
 
        IDtag = ""; //Inicialmente IDtag deve estar vazia.
        
        // Verifica se existe uma Tag presente
        if ( !LeitorRFID.PICC_IsNewCardPresent() || !LeitorRFID.PICC_ReadCardSerial() ) {
            delay(50);
            return;
        }
        
        // Pega o ID da Tag através da função LeitorRFID.uid e Armazena o ID na variável IDtag        
        for (byte i = 0; i < LeitorRFID.uid.size; i++) {        
            //IDtag.concat(String(LeitorRFID.uid.uidByte[i], HEX));
            IDtag.concat(String(LeitorRFID.uid.uidByte[i]));
        }        
        Serial.println(IDtag);
        
        
        //Compara o valor do ID lido com os IDs armazenados no vetor TagsCadastradas[]
        /*for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(TagsCadastradas)/sizeof(String)); i++) {
          if(  IDtag.equalsIgnoreCase(TagsCadastradas[i])  ){
              Permitido = true; //Variável Permitido assume valor verdadeiro caso o ID Lido esteja cadastrado
          }
        }*/
        
        /////////////////////////Problema ocorre a partir da execução da função VerificaCodigoRfid()
        String returnValue = "";
        returnValue = VerificaCodigoRfid();
        if(returnValue == "1"){
          Permitido = true;
        }else{
          Permitido = false;
        }
        /////////////////////////Fim da bronca 
        
        if(Permitido == true) acessoLiberado(); //Se a variável Permitido for verdadeira será chamada a função acessoLiberado()        
        else acessoNegado(); //Se não será chamada a função acessoNegado()
 
        delay(2000); //aguarda 2 segundos para efetuar uma nova leitura
}

void acessoLiberado(){
  Serial.println("Executando Função acessoLiberado");
  Serial.println("Tag Cadastrada: " + IDtag); //Exibe a mensagem "Tag Cadastrada" e o ID da tag não cadastrada
    efeitoPermitido();  //Chama a função efeitoPermitido()
    Permitido = false;  //Seta a variável Permitido como false novamente
}
 
void acessoNegado(){
  Serial.println("Executando Função acessoNegado");
  Serial.println("Tag NAO Cadastrada: " + IDtag); //Exibe a mensagem "Tag NAO Cadastrada" e o ID da tag cadastrada
  efeitoNegado(); //Chama a função efeitoNegado()
}
 
void efeitoPermitido(){  
  Serial.println("Executando Função efeitoPermitido");
  int qtd_bips = 1; //definindo a quantidade de bips
  for(int j=0; j<qtd_bips; j++){
    //Ligando o buzzer com uma frequência de 1500 hz e ligando o led verde.
    portaLiberada = 1;
    tone(BUZZER,1500);
    digitalWrite(LED_VERMELHO, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED_VERDE, LOW);
    delay(1000);
    
    //Desligando o buzzer e led verde.      
    noTone(BUZZER);
    digitalWrite(LED_VERMELHO, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED_VERDE, HIGH);
    //returnValue == "0";
    delay(500);
  } 
  Serial.println("AUTORIZADO"); 
}
 
void efeitoNegado(){  
  Serial.println("Executando Função efeitoNegado");
  int qtd_bips = 3;  //definindo a quantidade de bips
  for(int j=0; j<qtd_bips; j++){   
    //Ligando o buzzer com uma frequência de 500 hz e ligando o led vermelho.
    tone(BUZZER,500);
    digitalWrite(LED_VERMELHO, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(LED_VERDE, LOW);   
    delay(100); 
    //Desligando o buzzer e o led vermelho.
    noTone(BUZZER);
    digitalWrite(LED_VERMELHO, LOW);
    digitalWrite(LED_VERDE, HIGH);
    delay(100);
  }  
}

//Faz a validação se o RFID está liberado para acessar o local
String VerificaCodigoRfid(){
    Serial.println("Executando Função VerificaCodigoRfid");
    client.print("GET /sisconp2/acesso/verificar_acesso.php?acao=verificar_acesso&rfid=");
    client.print(IDtag);
    client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: 147.1.0.84");
    client.println("Connection: keep-alive");
    //client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
    return LerPagina();
}

//Faz a leitura da página para verificar se o acesso está liberado ou não
//Recebe o resultado na página de <0> ou <1>
String LerPagina(){
  Serial.println("Executando Função LerPagina");
  stringPos = 0;
  memset( &inString, 0, 32 ); //clear inString memory
  digitalWrite(REDE, LOW);
  while(true){//passou aqui
    if (client.available()) {
      char c = client.read();
      Serial.write(c);
      if (c == '<' ) {        //'<' is our begining character
        startRead = true;     //Ready to start reading the part 
      }else if(startRead){
        if(c != '>'){         //'>' is our ending character
          inString[stringPos] = c;
          stringPos ++;
        }else{
          startRead = false;
          client.stop();
          client.flush();
          Serial.println("disconnecting.");
          return inString;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Esquema eletrônico Nanoshield x Arduino

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esquema eletrônico RFID RC522 x Arduino
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]